# Solutions of the congruence $x^{a}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I need to find all solutions to this congruence -

$x^{k}\equiv 1 \pmod{p}$  , where **p is a prime**.

What is the general way to find this?
I searched it a lot , and could just find out that the number of solutions are **gcd ( k , p-1 ) .**

For example, for $x^{5} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$ , the answers can be 1, 3, 4, 5, 9 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions of $x^k \equiv 1 \bmod p$ are exactly the same as the solutions of $x^d \equiv 1 \bmod p$ for $d=\gcd(k,p-1)$, which has exactly $d$ solutions, because $U(p)$, the group of units mod $p$, is cyclic.

Finding the solutions typically require knowing a generator $g$ of $U(p)$, aka a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) mod $p$. The solutions are then $g^{mi}$ for $m=\frac{p-1}{d}$ and $i=0,\dots,d-1$.

[No efficient method is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots) for finding primitive roots, though [typically there is a small one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Order_of_magnitude_of_primitive_roots).

In your example, $2$ is a primitive root mod $11$ and so the solutions of $x^5 \equiv 1 \bmod 11$ are the powers of $2^2=4$, which are $1,4,5,9,3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please state an example or some source related to this generator?  I am a beginner and have no idea about this.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for causing you trouble. But I couldn't get the method on wikipedia link. I mean for the example mentioned, how we got 2 and solutions -1,4,5,9,3? ETF of n here turns out to be 10, but how to go further?

Comment: The simple way is to compute all powers of $2 \bmod 11$ and see that only $2^{10}$ is $1$.

Comment: Yeah got this part of getting powers. And how you obtained g=2?

Comment: Ohk got it thnx :)